# How do you find the complex amplitude for polychromatic light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, interference

The complex amplitude of a plane wave of wavenumber $k$ having traveled distance $x$ is given by: $U=U_0 \exp(ikx)$ And the intensity is: $I=|U|^2$

For polychromatic light you simply integrate over the range of $k$. However, integrating $U$ over a large enough wavenumber range or distance will cancel out the complex values resulting in a total complex amplitude nearing 0. So this would mean that polychromatic light has no intensity.

What am I doing wrong here?